# how to have a view 1 item as overlay in index items webpage?

Tags: ajax, facebook, overlay

I require two scenarios to work:

Scenario 1:
When my users click on http://example.com/items/3 or type the url into the url bar

they will be directed to a webpage that has the item:id 3 shown in an overlay.

When they click on the x in the overlay, they will either be shown /items index page (if they are logged in) OR the signup page (if they are not).

When the item:id 3 is shown in overlay, the url in the bar will be /items/3
When the /items is shown, the url will be /items

Scenario 2:
My logged in user is now at /items index page.

She clicks on a /items/3 link. Instead of redirecting, the item:id 3 is shown in an overlay.

WHen she clicks on the x in the overlay, she is back at /items index page.

When the item:id 3 is shown in overlay, the url in the bar will be /items/3
When the /items is shown, the url will be /items

**What I want to achieve:**

Both scenarios have the same look and feel especially for logged in users. the only difference is the starting point of the flow.

Scenario 1 starts from the /items/3. Scenario 2 starts from /items.

Both scenarios require the url in the url bar to change depending on whether the overlay is turned on or off.

**What I have already done:**

I have made Scenario 2 to work using ajax to fetch the data to populate the overlay.

However the url does not change regardless what is shown.

Scenario 1 is totally not done at all. I do not even know how to begin.

**An example I found that displays Scenario 1**

In facebook feed, your url is typically www.facebook.com

When you click on a photo, you will see an overlay with the photo and the url changes to something like
photo.php?fbid=10151124518657496&set=a.10150255078032496.325973.527477495&type=1&theater

When you close your overlay, you go back to your feed and the url changes back to www.facebook.com

**My question**

What is the basic architectural solution to achieve my objectives?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to use HTML5 History API.

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

I will fill in with more details for the long answer soon.